# NOT LOGGED INITIALLY IN Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I h'v found following error in db2 diaglog " the commit processing on "table" that used not logged initially has been initiated but when i checked table DDL. I didn't find not logged initially option there and not even table was altered recently. So, how can they use this option without altering table..

Thanks

Comment: copy and paste your code and error message

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <tabname> ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY
```

could be executed at any point in time and will not be reflected in the DDL as it is a temporary state and will only last to the next commit.

Attention: Take care with this option - I even would recommend to avoid it - because any error during this state will result in an unuseable table.

Background: This functionality was originally allowed to create and "load" a table in one step without logging the addition of data. Later it was allowed at any time after the creation as well. It was usful with and additional opton "WITH EMPTY TABLE" to get rid of table data efficiently before the truncate table command was added.

Comment: To clarify, a long time ago it was not possible to issue the statement that Michael lists *unless* the table had been created with the `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` attribute. This requirement was lifted, which may be the cause of @lucky's misunderstanding.